# In a casual conversation to a child, is it okay to say "a skirt" when you are actually referring to "a shift or pinafore or jumper"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

According to [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shift_1?q=shift)

This is **a shift**

[image]

The **black one** in this picture is a **jumper or pinafore**

[image]

And a skirt normally doesn't have the top as the **blue one** in this picture

[image]

And say you are a parent and you don't know much about clothes and in a casual conversation to a child.

is it okay to say "**a skirt**" when you are actually referring to "**a shift or pinafore or jumper**"?

Comment: To me the pictures show from top to bottom: a dress, a short dress, which could be called a top if worn with trousers and a skirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually call an all-in-one female garment a *dress*. A *skirt* is either a separate lower garment or the part of a dress or coat that hangs below the waist.